# how to set visibility of MainWindow controls like stackpanel from another .xaml page

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am creating one sample WPF application in MVVM pattern to implement  master page-content page concept.
   In my wpf application I have one MainWindow page and 3 usercontrols  say Page1, Page2 and  Page3.

The MainWindow.xaml contains oner grid, one stackpanel and one frame.

Grid in MainWindow.xaml contains one image control and the stackpanel contains one TextBlock and 3 buttons.

This frame is filled or loaded first by page as follows:

```
        // Load and show the MainWindow

        MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        Navigator.NavigationService = main.NavigationFrame.NavigationService;
        main.DataContext = vm;
        main.Show();

        // Load and navigate to the first page
        Page1ViewModel pagevm = new Page1ViewModel();
        Page1 p1 = new Page1();
        p1.DataContext = pagevm;
        Navigator.NavigationService.Navigate(p1);
```

By using  this I am able to navigate from page1 to page2 and then from page2 to page3.

Here my problem is initially the stack panel should be disable means while displaying page1 and page2.
   But while navigating from page2 to page3 that means whenever i am showing the page3 the stack panel which was in MainWindow should be enable and the buttons will be able to perform their click events in page3 only.

Please let me know the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the current page to the MainWindowViewModel and add a property that returns, whether the `StackPanel` is enabled:

```
MainWindowViewModel:
private Page _currentPage = null;
public Page CurrentPage
{
    get { return _currentPage; }
    set
    {
        _currentPage = value;
        Notify("CurrentPage");
        Notify("StackPanelEnabled");          
    }
}

public bool StackPanelEnabled
{
    get { return CurrentPage is Page3; }
}
```

`Notify` is a helper method that raises the `PropertyChanged` event. Bind the `Content` property of the `Frame` to the `CurrentPage`:

```
<Frame Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

Use it:

```
Page1ViewModel pagevm = new Page1ViewModel();
Page1 p1 = new Page1();
p1.DataContext = pagevm;
vm.CurrentPage = p1;
```